# How to use dynamic generated id to get Value of label using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox, label

I have a GridView, in which i have two controls, Label and Textbox. I want to get the Label's value on textbox's change event.

I have used the following Method to get this. but i am not getting the Value

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id$=txtInvoiceInDollar]').change(function (e) {
            var textboxid = this.id;

            var streetaddress = textboxid.substr(0, textboxid.lastIndexOf('_'));
            var exactId = streetaddress + '_lblSaleExt';
            var valuetes = $('"#"' + ctl00_ItemMain_grd_Invoice_ctl02_lblSaleExt + '"').val();
            alert(valuetes);

            return false;
        });
    });
```

HTML code is:

```
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;" id="ctl00_ItemMain_grd_Invoice" class="result result-text">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="head">
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice','Sort$PricingName')">Pricing Name</a></th>
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice','Sort$Variation')">Variation</a></th>
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice','Sort$StoreName')">StoreName</a></th>
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice','Sort$Quantity')">Quantity</a></th>
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice','Sort$ProductID')">Product</a></th>
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice','Sort$Descr')">Description</a></th>
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice','Sort$SalePrice')">Sale Price</a></th>
                <th scope="col">Sale Extended</th>
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice','Sort$CostPrice')">Cost Price</a></th>
                <th scope="col">Invoice $</th>
                <th scope="col">Invoice %</th>
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice','Sort$RemainingInDollar')">Remaining $</a></th>
                <th scope="col"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice','Sort$RemainingInPercentage')">Remaining %</a></th>
                <th scope="col">Invoice $</th>
                <th scope="col">Invoice %</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td>Replacement of existing bla bla</td>
                <td>True</td>
                <td>KFC</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Prod1</td>
                <td>Desc desc</td>
                <td>21.32</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="right" id="ctl00_ItemMain_grd_Invoice_ctl02_lblSaleExt">42.64</span>
                </td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="right" id="ctl00_ItemMain_grd_Invoice_ctl02_lblInvoiceInDollar">0</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class="right" id="ctl00_ItemMain_grd_Invoice_ctl02_lblInvoiceInPer">0</span>
                </td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="right" id="ctl00_ItemMain_grd_Invoice_ctl02_txtInvoiceInDollar" value="0" name="ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice$ctl02$txtInvoiceInDollar">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="right" id="ctl00_ItemMain_grd_Invoice_ctl02_txtInvoiceInPer" value="0" name="ctl00$ItemMain$grd_Invoice$ctl02$txtInvoiceInPer">
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Please help me, how can i get the value of label

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, i have fixed it by my own.

here is the solution:

```
 $('[id$=txtInvoiceInDollar]').change(function (e) {
            var textboxid = this.id;

            var streetaddress = textboxid.substr(0, textboxid.lastIndexOf('_'));
            var exactId = streetaddress + '_lblSaleExt';
            var id2 = $("[id$=" + exactId + "]").text();
            alert(id2);

            return false;
        });
```

Thanks for investigate on the issue.

Comment: if `exactId` is really an exact id of one HTML elements, you'd better go with `$('#' + exactId)`, much better in terms of performance. Also, you'd better go with CSS class name selectors instead of dirty ID tricks, eg `$('.lblSaleExt')` or `$('.tbxInvoiceInDollar')` instead of `$("[id$=" + this.id.substr(0, this.id.lastIndexOf('_')) + '_lblSaleExt' + "]")` or `$('[id$=txtInvoiceInDollar]')` which one is more readable ? :)